# show action result in same page in struts2

Tags: ajax, jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-json-plugin

I am trying to show result in same page but it is showing result in separate page. The action is adding attribute to the session, I want to show the value of that attribute as a result.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
   <sx:head/>
   <sj:head/> 
  </head>
<body>
   <%@include file="menu.jsp" %> `
<sj:tabbedpanel id="localtabs" cssStyle="content-left">
  <sj:tab id="tab1"  target="tone" label="Recommend Tests"/>
  <sj:tab id="tab2" target="ttwo" label="Recommend Dose"/>
  <div id="tone">
     <s:form action="saveSuggestedTests" theme="xhtml">
        <s:optiontransferselect
         label="Select Tests"
         name="leftNumber"
         list="%{activeTestsMap}"
         doubleName="rightNumber"
         doubleList="returnMap"
         labelposition="top"
        />
        <sj:submit name="submit" value="Submit" indicator="indicator"  targets="result"/>
     </s:form>
     <div id="result" class="result ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>        
  </div>
```

`struts.xml` have following configuration

```
<action name="saveSuggestedTests" class="org.arshiya.struts.action.tests.TestsManagerHelper" method="saveSuggestedTests">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/result.jsp</result>
             <result name="error">/WEB-INF/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="login">/WEB-INF/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/WEB-INF/createUser.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: The settings looks correct to me. What's in the result.jsp?

Comment: What do you mean "in separate page"? Does it displays result.jsp in a new page or current page is being refreshed?

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply as I am new to this site ans was looking for answer status in profile page. @aleksandr-m it shows result.jsp in same page but page gets refreshed so my tabs are gone.
I want result to be displayed in same tab (ajax type) by refreshing same page/half page without affecting tabs. but result.jsp opens in new page.

Comment: @Quincy result.jsp doesn't contain anything other than printing action result put in session.
<s:property value="#session.actionResult"/>

Comment: The code you have posted should work just fine. Do you get exceptions or javascript errors? Also where do you have put a `<sj:head>` tag?

Comment: @Aleksandr-m I have following code above the tabbedpanel code shown in first code snippet

Comment: I am not getting any exception or javascript error but result page opening and showing result. 
instead of showing code snippet over here, I added it in the above code snippet itself to make it more readable. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You are mixing `dojo` with `jQuery` it might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @aleksandr-m  tried removing dojo but even then it has same behavior :(

Comment: Are you sure that there are not any javascript errors? Use `console` tab of firebug to see javascript errors.

Comment: I have tried the similar thing and it is working fine for me.